# X1 battery discharging stuck at 7%

Tags: linux, battery, thinkpad, reset

The old battery of my X1 Carbon 4th Gen. was dying, and the battery readings became unreliable. So I had it replaced (with an official battery replacement).

Now the problem with the old battery *and* new battery (thus it's some calibration problem, and not one inherent with the battery) is the following:

When I *discharge* the battery, the battery reading becomes stuck at x% (currently at 7%) and does not drop further. I can still use the laptop for hours; until it suddenly drops to 0% and my laptop shuts down.
`sudo tlp-stat -b` shows me without changing

`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =   3030 [mWh]`

`Charge                                                      =    7.2 [%]`

When I plug in the charger after a while, while the battery shows 7%, the charging LED is *off* and the system, as well as `tlp-stat` tell me it's *not charging* (even though it is charging).

Furthermore, `tlp` does sometimes not respect my charging threshold at 80%. It charges until it displays 79% and when I pull out the charger, it displays 99%.

I tried resetting the power management (holding down the power button for 1 min when off).  On the next boot it discharged to 0%, but got stuck at 10 mWh. I tried `sudo tlp recalibrate` but it couldn't finish due to being stuck again.
The following boot, the charge again got stuck at 7%.

Are there any other ways to reset/recalibrate the battery?

Comment: I have that very machine siting beside me. I replaced the battery halfway through useful life with no issues.  Try installing Lenovo Vantage, update it, and run the Battery calibration cycle - takes some hours.  When done restart and test. If still issues see if you can have the battery replaced.

Comment: Resetting power management often requires 1. Removing the battery. 2. Unplugging the charger. 3. Holding the power button for a minute.  4. Plug in power but not battery. 5. Boot, then power down. See https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-hard-reset-a-laptop BTW, discharging a lithium battery, or even automotive lead-acid battery, completely **greatly** shortens it's service life, and might even destroy it in one go. (Ni-Cd, Ni-Fe and NiMH cells are less likely to be damaged by total discharge.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes, I am very aware that completely discharging lithium batteries can destroy them. In fact, the one time the charge dropped from 7% to 0% and shut down, it couldn't run without the power cord for about an hour... I will check out the guide for nonremovable batteries, thanks!
@ John I'll try that first!